# Instruction don't work while checking given message content in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make one-word-story bot, but it don't work. I want to check if content of message equals 'the_end', so bot can join words and send finished story, but it doesn't work. I checked if my instruction run without 'if' and it worked. I tried an 'if' negation, too. Can someone say what's going on? Here's my code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

words = []

story = []

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="story ")

@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(status=discord.Status.online, activity=discord.Game("story help"))
    print("Ready")

@bot.command()
async def begin(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Ready")
    message = await bot.wait_for('message')
    if message == 'the_end':
        await ctx.send(' '.join(story))
    else:
        words = message.content.split()
        if len(words) <= 1:
            story.append(words[0])
            words.clear()

bot.run(token)
```

Comment: could you elaborate more on what didn't work? Did you got an error message?

Comment: No, I dont get an error, when I send 'the_end' message (which is in 'if' statement) instruction in this 'if' statement isn't runned and I don't know why.

Comment: are you sure that your code goes inside the `if`? have you tried adding a print before the send to see if the if is correct?

Comment: No, I don't tried it. I will test it.
Edit: It don't works.

Comment: You need to do message.content rather than just message I believe.

Comment: I checked what happens when you send an message (printed content of list story) and it's appending this one word forever! I don't know how to fix it.